# wherein Laravel Route parameter

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose I have a route like this :

```
$api->group(['prefix' => 'Tag/{type}'], function ($api) {

});
```

As you can see there is a required `type` parameter.

Now I want `type` parameter can only one of items of an array that is defined in a config file like this :

```
return [
    'name' => 'Tag',
    'types' => [
        'product' => 'product',
        'user'    => 'user'
    ]
];
```

Means `type` can be `product` or `user` only. I know that I should use Regular Expression Constraints but I do not know how ?

Comment: which package are you using ?

Comment: https://github.com/dingo/api

Answer (score -1):

simple!!!

create a helper file(I hope u know how to create a helper file) and make a function that return an implode version. for instance.
you created a arrayconfig.php in config folder and the code inside it is

```
    return [
       'name' => 'Tag',
       'types' => [
           'product' => 'product',
           'user'    => 'user'
       ]
   ];
```

now in helper.php create a function

```
    function typechecker(){
        $array = config()->get('arrayConfig.types');
        return implode("|",$arr);
    }
```

you must remember you add it to composer.json file and run a command in console

```
    composer dump-autoload
```

after adding helper files
what is to be added in composer.json
if you create a folder helpers in app and your file path is

```
    app/Helpers/helpers.php
```

Your composer.json will be something like this

```
    "autoload": {
         "classmap": [
              ....
         ],
         "files": [
             "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
         ],
         "psr-4": {
              ....
         }
    }
```

just concentrate on files. rest of the section is already there. I added all code to make it understandable

Final step in your route

```
    $api->group(['prefix' => 'Tag/{type}'], function ($api) {})->where('type', typechecker());
```

Cheers!!!

**N.B** it's 100% workable. If it does not work, that means you did something wrong

Comment: Why I asked to create a helper function? because you can create many functions in helpers.php (no class, just funcs) and those are accessible anywhere. if you don't want that, you can simply do this
            $api->group(['prefix' => 'Tag/{type}'], function ($api) {})->where('type', 'product|user');